# Swift 3 - Como instanciar uma View Controller?

Tags: swift, storyboard, uiviewcontroller

Preciso trabalhar com um método com atributos que estão em outra ViewController mas não consigo o fazer.
O que estou tentando:

```
let notasViewController: NotasViewController()
```

E também:

```
let notasViewController: NotasViewController = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NotasViewController") as! NotasViewController
```

Sempre retorna EXC_BAD_ACESS ou um erro dizendo que meu Storyboard não contém esse View Controller
Alguma ajuda? Grato!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Serão basicamente 2 etapas a serem feitas no Storyboard:

1. No seu `Main.storyboard`, selecione o ViewController desejado e modifique a classe do mesmo para NotasViewController.
2. Modifique o campo Storyboard ID, com o nome do identificador que você utilizará no código, no caso do seu código, você está utilizando: "NotasViewController"

As configurações ficariam dessa forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A caixinha "Use Storyboard ID" não é obrigatória de estar marcada, ela serve caso você queira deixar o "Restoration ID" com o mesmo ID do identificador na Storyboard.

Feito isso, vá até a classe do View Controller que você deseja ter uma instância da classe `NotasViewController` e utilize o mesmo código que você utilizou:

```
let notasViewController: NotasViewController = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NotasViewController") as! NotasViewController
```

Sendo assim você terá acesso aos métodos da classe `NotasViewController` através da constante `notasViewController`.

Answer (score -1):

Pode fazer dessa forma para criar uma nova instância do ViewController:

```
let notasViewController = NotasViewController()
```